# Spring Boot not-decoding special characters inside URL Parameter when running Integration Tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I have a GET Endpoint in the Spring Boot RestController that is accepting an email as a URL Parameter ( I know this is not so good idea, but I cannot change this as of now).

**EmailController.java**

```
package com.example.sospringtestdecodingissue;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/email")
@Slf4j
public class EmailController {

    @GetMapping
    public String inputEmail(@RequestParam String email) {
      log.info("Received input email {}", email);
        return email;
    }
}
```

When I run the application and test this controller by providing various emails as input with special characters, the endpoint decodes the URL parameters as expected. Here is an example:

**Request-1**: `curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/api/email?email=test%2Bemail@gmail.com"`

**Response-1**: `test+email@gmail.com`

**Request-2**: `curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/api/email?email=test%26email@gmail.com"`

**Response-2**: `test&email@gmail.com`

**Request-3**: `curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/api/email?email=test+email@gmail.com"`

**Response-3**: `test email@gmail.com`

**Request-4**: `curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/api/email?email=test&email@gmail.com"`

**Response-4**: `test`

I created an Integration Test for this endpoint, and I wrote a test for the above-mentioned endpoint, with the above Request and Response as my input test data and expected output.

But for some reason, the email parameter is not decoded during the integration test, here is the Integration Test:

**EmailControllerMockMvcTest.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class EmailControllerMockMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("inputValues")
    void testEmailInput(String inputEmail, String expectedOutputEmail) throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/email")
                        .param("email", inputEmail))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string(expectedOutputEmail));
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> inputValues() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("test+email.com", "test email.com"),
                Arguments.of("test&email.com", "test"),
                Arguments.of("test%2Bemail.com", "test+email.com"),
                Arguments.of("test%26email.com", "test&email.com")
        );
    }

}
```

I was under the impression that this is due to the use of MockMvc as it uses a Mocked Servlet Environment, hence I wrote another test using `TestRestTemplate` but to my surprise, I still see the same behavior.

**EmailControllerTestRestTemplateIT.java**

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class EmailControllerTestRestTemplateIT {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("inputValues")
    void testEmailInput(String inputEmail, String expectedOutputEmail) throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:" + port + "/api/email?email={email}",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                String.class,
                inputEmail);

        Assertions.assertThat(responseEntity.getBody())
                .isEqualTo(expectedOutputEmail);
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> inputValues() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("test+email.com", "test email.com"),
                Arguments.of("test&email.com", "test"),
                Arguments.of("test%2Bemail.com", "test+email.com"),
                Arguments.of("test%26email.com", "test&email.com")
        );
    }

}
```

I have the link to the full source code here with the failing test suite - https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/so-spring-test-decoding-issue

You can check out and try it yourself if you want.

Can anyone please clarify why there is this discrepancy between the actual server and the Integration Test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your tests are failing is that there is a URI encoding happening with your CURL request that you are not accounting for in your tests.

I have modified your RestTemplate tests to what I believe should work.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("inputValues")
void testEmailInput(String inputEmail, String expectedOutputEmail) throws Exception {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:" + port + "/api/email?email=" + inputEmail);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange(uri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            String.class);

    Assertions.assertThat(responseEntity.getBody())
            .isEqualTo(expectedOutputEmail);
}
```